# ORA-01877: exception when using oracle to_char for Date value passing from Java

Tags: java, oracle, plsql, timezone, timestamp

Anyone had idea on how to fix this issue?

**Note:** simulation step is at the last section of this topic.

Currently I receiving exception **ORA-01877: string is too long for internal buffer** at this line of code at plsql program

`v_old_val := TO_CHAR (p_val);`

p_val is declared as TIMESTAMP, value is passed from trigger when the table has new record inserted or updated from a java application.

After having some debugging, I found out this issue happened only when below conditions are met:

1. application insert record into that table with **date under year 1978**
2. timezone at client side is **Asia/Shanghai**
3. timezone in app server and db server is **Asia/Singapore**

Sample Data captured from application log:

client side >> Thu Jul 27 00:00:00 CST 1978 (User key in date)

server side >> Wed Jul 26 23:30:00 SGT 1978 (Date to be insert into db)

**PLSQL function**

```
PROCEDURE writelog_t (
  p_val      IN   TIMESTAMP
)
IS
BEGIN
     v_old_val :=  TO_CHAR (p_val); 
END
```

**Table**

```
CREATE   TABLE birthday(
  KEY             NUMBER(12)                    NOT NULL,
  birth_dt        TIMESTAMP(6)
)
```

**Trigger**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "BIRTHDAY_TRG"
AFTER DELETE OR INSERT OR UPDATE
ON BIRTHDAY
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN  
 IF NOT DELETING THEN 
  plsql_prod.Writelog_t(:NEW.BIRTH_DT); 
 END IF; 
END
```

---

**Update:**
I had tried to commented out the line that causing the issue and commit the data into a working table. But when I try to query for the inserted data by using Toad(Version 8.6.1.0), Toad showing the same error and crashed.

`SELECT TO_CHAR(birth_dt) FROM working_table`

[ORA-01877: string is too long for internal buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyFHQ.png)

[Call Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8heCC.png)

---

**SIMULATION**

I had found out a way to simulate this issue.

```
CREATE   TABLE birthday(
  KEY             NUMBER(12)                    NOT NULL,
  birth_dt        TIMESTAMP(6)
)
```

Sample Java Program

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeZoneTestCase {

    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss a";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String dateInString = "27-07-1978 12:00:00 AM";
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        try {
            // connection is the data source we used to fetch the data from
            Connection connection = establishConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement updateTotal = connection
                    .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO birthday (key, birth_dt) VALUES (0,?)");
            statement
                    .executeUpdate("INSERT INTO birthday (key, birth_dt) VALUES (0, TIMESTAMP '1978-07-27 00:00:00 Asia/Singapore')");

            TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Shanghai"));
            Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
            System.out.println("Date (CST) : " + date);

            TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
            Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            System.out.println("Date (SGT) : " + calendar.getTime());
            updateTotal.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));

            updateTotal.executeUpdate();
            updateTotal.close();
            connection.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public static Connection establishConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            String db2URL = "Please fill in your db url here";
            String userName = "Please fill in your db login username";
            String password = "Please fill in your db login password";
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db2URL, userName, password);
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }

}
```

and then run this in db then you will get the issue

`select * from birhtday`

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including a minimal snippet of the java code which stores the date in the database (and any associated Oracle procedures), the DDL for the table and the code for the trigger that is sufficient to replicate the problem.

Comment: I presume `v_old_val`  is declared in the package spec `plsql_prod`. If that is the case, check  the variable length defined for `v_old_val`  in  `plsql_prod` . Change it to a larger value.

Comment: @KaushikNayak Hi thanks for answering my question, the v_old_val is declared in package spec and size has already increment to Varchar2(4000 Byte) and the error still exists

Comment: @MT0 Hi, I had upload the db related code, and for java side no special handling just retrieving the data from input field then send it to server and server will use persistence EntityManager persist() to do the insertion.

Comment: @MT0, Hi,I had provided a snippet of the java code for replicate the problem.

Comment: @user9054854 Not seeing an error unless I drop the size of `V_OLD_VAR` down so no timestamps fit into it - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8c120/1

Comment: @MT0, you using the trigger and plsql to do the testing? maybe you can use the most bottom "simulation" section, just a table with a simple java program already can hit the exception.

Comment: @MT0 I had tried it out if only using DB it wont have any issue, but if you simulate it with java program then only the issue will appears

Comment: What happens if you use `SELECT TO_CHAR( birth_dt, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF6' ) FROM Birthday`? If that works then what is your `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT`? You can find it out using: `SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT'`